# Error when posting and receiving URL as a parameter in a request post

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I am receiving a 422 error when trying to post a url to a docker container, the goal is to send a url to a docker file with selenium to scrape for the title tag on the website.

The file that posts the url to the docker container:

```
SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER=os.environ.get("SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER")
SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT=os.environ.get("SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT")
def extract_text_via_scraper_service(website):
    answer = {}
    if SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT is None:
        return answer
    if SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER is None:
        return answer
    if website is None:
        return answer
   
    headers={
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER}"
    }
    
    print(SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER) # returns correct secret key
    print(SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT) # returns correct url
    
   
    r = requests.post(SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT, json={"webiste": website}, headers=headers)
    print(r) # returns <Response [422]>
    print(r.headers) # returns {'Date': 'Fri, 05 Nov 2021 11:50:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '92', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'cache-control': 'private', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '6a95dde13b7954f7-SYD'}
    print(r.text) # returns {"detail":[{"loc":["query","website"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
    print(r.json) # returns <bound method Response.json of <Response [422]>>
    
    if r.status_code in range(200, 299):
        if r.headers.get("content-type") == 'application/json':
            answer = r.json()
    print(answer)
    return answer
```

receiving file:

```
import pathlib
import os
import io
from functools import lru_cache
from fastapi import (
    FastAPI,
    Header,
    HTTPException,
    Depends,
    Request,
    )
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_auth_token: str
    debug: bool = False
    echo_active: bool = False
    app_auth_token_prod: str = None
    skip_auth: bool = False

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"

@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    return Settings()

settings = get_settings()
DEBUG=settings.debug

BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
UPLOAD_DIR = BASE_DIR / "uploads"


app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(BASE_DIR / "templates"))


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse) # http GET -> JSON
def home_view(request: Request, settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "abc": 123})

def verify_auth(authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    """
    Authorization: Bearer <token>
    {"authorization": "Bearer <token>"}
    """
    if settings.debug and settings.skip_auth:
        return
    if authorization is None:
        raise HTTPException(detail="Invalid endpoint", status_code=401)
    label, token = authorization.split()
    if token != settings.app_auth_token:
        raise HTTPException(detail="Invalid endpoint", status_code=401)


@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(website:str, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    verify_auth(authorization, settings)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(website)

    
    title = "Sorry, we failed to get the correct name"
    

    #title
    try:
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//title")
        title = title.get_attribute("innerText")
    except:
        pass
    
    print(title)
   
    return{"results": title, "original": title}
```

I think I cannot pass it as a string value and this is why I am getting error code 422?

Comment: How does the `data`  collected in receiving file:?

Comment: I have edited to show the full function. The goal is to pass the url to selenium driver. Works in server console.

Comment: Can you try with `json={'url': 'https://www.google.com'}` instead of `data={'url': 'https://www.google.com'}`

Comment: I have no way of testing this (neither does anyone else because you haven't offered a reproducible code fragment). However, it *may* be that you should replace the *data* keyword with *json*

Comment: @BrutusForcus - I have update the details, your suggestion seemed to help, I am now getting the following from `print(r.text)` `{"detail":[{"loc":["query","website"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}` and from `print(r.json)`
`<bound method Response.json of <Response [422]>>`

Comment: Are you sure that the dictionary key **webiste** is correct?

Comment: Yes it is definitely they key, I just did a full redeploy of the docker container and I've edited above just a copy and paste of that whole file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact I was receiving the post request as a query parameter instead of a request body. Relevant FastApi documentation can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#request-body-path-query-parameters), note the following:

The function parameters will be recognized as follows:

- If the parameter is also declared in the path, it will be used as a
  path parameter.
- If the parameter is of a singular type (like int,    float, str,
  bool, etc) it will be interpreted as a query parameter.
- If the parameter is declared to be of the type of a Pydantic model,
  it will be interpreted as a request body.

old:

```
@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(website, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    verify_auth(authorization, settings)
```

new:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    website: str

@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(requested_url: Item, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
driver.get(requested_url.website)
```